# Capture diag frame data of Qualcomm Quectel modem using an open-source app in C++

Tags: c++, diagnostics, qualcomm, data-link-layer, quectel

I want to capture (and maybe dissect) the diag data obtained from Qualcomm Quectel modem (EC25) in linux. I have done this for mobile devices with Qualcomm chip-set in android environment using some opensource projects such as [mobile-insight](https://github.com/mobile-insight/mobileinsight-core) and [SnoopSnitch](https://opensource.srlabs.de/projects/snoopsnitch). So I can dissect almost all the diag data obtained from air interface like RRC Signaling Message and ...

Now, I need an open source program in C++ to capture diag frames from Quectel chipset. I know that [osmocom](https://osmocom.org/projects/quectel-modems/wiki) has similar project in this area. So what is the best open source c++ app to use? (If osmocom is the best, please guide me that project because I'm somewhat ambiguous in the osmocom document)

Answer (score 1):

> So what is the best open source c++ app to use?

Define "the best". There can be many criteria: completeness of the implementation, protocol support, maintenance status and so on. What exactly do you mean?

> I need an open source program in C++ to capture diag frames from Quectel chipset. I know that osmocom has similar project in this area.

Osmocom has https://git.osmocom.org/osmo-qcdiag/ in C. Unfortunately, this project has no wiki (https://osmocom.org/projects/osmo-qcdiag/wiki shows empty page), but there is a brief [README](https://git.osmocom.org/osmo-qcdiag/tree/README) .

Building osmo-qcdiag from source is rather typical. You would need to have libosmocore: either build it from [source](https://osmocom.org/projects/libosmocore/wiki/Libosmocore), or install from [packages](https://osmocom.org/projects/cellular-infrastructure/wiki/Nightly_Builds). Then do the following:

```sh
$ git clone https://git.osmocom.org/osmo-qcdiag
$ cd osmo-qcdiag/src/
$ make
```

After running make, you'll find the `osmo-qcdiag-log` binary.

```sh
$ ./osmo-qcdiag-log /dev/ttyUSB0
```

osmo-qcdiag is not actively maintained and is not user friendly at all. It simply gets diag data from the modem, decodes known packets and sends them over UDP/GSMTAP. You can use Wireshark to dissect GSMTAP frames. That's it.

Personally I prefer using the following tools:

- https://github.com/P1sec/QCSuper, and
- https://github.com/fgsect/scat.

They both are user friendly and written in Python.